# Taking too long in navigating from one page to another in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

It's taking too long time to show up an page from another. I kept only value bindings to the controls which are pre-dedigned.
Can any one please help me in increasing the performance of navigating between the pages.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information.  What is on the pages?  What is you response time and what are you seeing?  How is the site hosted? Etc..

Answer (score 0):

Loading images or design elemets(like map) takes a lots of time before loading page. I am trying to call empty page first and by timer start to load design elements it become not more fast but at least you don't wait until create the page  . Also I use page.reset() method after i left the page it helps in some cases to reload the same pages performance. In all cases don't expect the performance of native app.